# Efficient Way to Identify and Change data types en mass with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have found a way to identify the datetime columns in a data frame and then apply strftime formatting to them all. However, I am trying to expand my skills with pandas and move away from using apply so answers that are more efficient would be great!
Here's some sample code...

```
import pandas as pd

# Create df
test_tz_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'With tz' : [(pd.to_datetime('today') - pd.DateOffset(days=1)).tz_localize(tz='America/Los_Angeles').tz_localize(None)]*2,
        'Without tz' : [(pd.to_datetime('today') - pd.DateOffset(days=1))]*2,
        'strings' : ['string a','string b']
    }
)

# Find the dt columns to edit
datetime_cols = test_tz_df.select_dtypes(include=["datetime64[ns]"]).columns.to_list()

# apply() strftime() formatting
test_tz_df[datetime_cols] = test_tz_df[datetime_cols].apply(lambda x : x.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: `strftime()` turns dates into strings; is that what your intent is? Or do you just want them to appear in that format when printed?

Comment: @VincentRupp yeah that is my intent

Comment: Why do you think apply is not a good solution? Don't forget you apply the transformation on a small subset of columns.

Comment: @Corralien since pandas operates on eager loading it would be nice to use an operation that will take advantage of  that such as `groupby()` which means it will perform well on  larger data sets. `apply()` does not take advantage of eager loading which means as data grows so does execution time... greatly. So, I want to learn more efficient ways as I go so I don't have to re learn approaches for different size data sets

Answer (score 1):

I have found that `.at[]` is faster than `.apply()`, `.iteritems()`, and `.loc[]`

Here is a sample implementation with timeit results:

```
#define functions to test
def use_apply(df):
  df = df.apply(lambda x : x.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
  return df

def use_loc(df):
  d = {c:[] for c in df.columns}
  for c in df.columns:
    s = df[c]
    for i in range(len(s)):
      d[c].append(s.at[i].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
  return pd.DataFrame(d)

#set up dataframe
t_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'With_tz' : [(pd.to_datetime('today') - pd.DateOffset(days=1)).tz_localize(tz='America/Los_Angeles').tz_localize(None)]*2,
        'Without_tz' : [(pd.to_datetime('today') - pd.DateOffset(days=2))]*2
    }
)

#timeit
print("With apply: ", timeit.timeit(lambda: use_apply(t_df), number=1000))
print("With .at: ", timeit.timeit(lambda: use_loc(t_df), number=1000))
```

Results:
With apply: 0.989

With .at: 0.357

That's a pretty significant time advantage, even though two loops seems like it would be ridiculous.

(You'll notice that I skipped the part of your question where you identify the datetime columns; I don't see a way to improve on that.)

Answer (score 1):

> `apply()` does not take advantage of eager loading which means as data grows so does execution time

You are right but not in your current scenario:

```
datetime_cols = test_tz_df.select_dtypes(include=["datetime64[ns]"]).columns.to_list()

for i in np.logspace(1, 7, 7, dtype=int):
    df1 = test_tz_df.reindex(test_tz_df.index.repeat(i))
    print(f'For {len(df1):,} records')
    %timeit test_tz_df[datetime_cols].apply(lambda x : x.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Output:

```
For 20 records
1.04 ms ± 16.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

For 200 records
1.01 ms ± 15.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

For 2,000 records
997 µs ± 11 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

For 20,000 records
1.03 ms ± 16.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

For 200,000 records
1.02 ms ± 9.58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

For 2,000,000 records
1.02 ms ± 12.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

For 20,000,000 records
1.03 ms ± 20.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

You make a "loop" on only two columns so looking for an alternative to `apply` is not relevant here.

Comment: by "loop" is this per iteration? So it's ~ 1ms x number of rows? So 200,000 rows would take 3.33 minutes (.001 X 200,000) and then 20,000,000 rows would take about 5 and a half hours (.001 X 20,000,000)? This type of total execution time is what I would like to avoid

Comment: A loop is not an iteration!!! It's a run case. It took 1.03 to process the whole dataframe (2 columns of 20,000,000 rows)

Comment: Oh wow, why is that the case?

Comment: Because you apply a transformation on a small subset of columns. It's different than apply an operation on each row without vectorization.